# ERROR: FacebookApiException [ 190 ]: Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token

Tags: php, facebook

What's wrong with this?

```
    public function hasAppPermission($permission) 
{
    return $this->api(array('method' => 'users.hasAppPermission', 'access_token' => $this->getAccessToken(), 'ext_perm' => $permission));
}
```

Output:

```
array(
['method'] => 'users.hasAppPermission'
...
['access_token'] => '290034239987|2.SvGXXig_x3yjCkz7QDz4Wg__.3600.2293826300-130050996538485|UcFS331a75AR389Vtjz9rgDmpUg'
...
['ext_perm'] => 'user_birthday'
...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing this in a home server like xampp or similar?
If it´s, there is the problem with authorization token. Because there are any valid certificate in localhost.

Comment: i am testing at localhost. What dou you mean with "valid certificate"?

Comment: Its beacuse feacebok API can not reach your local computer from the internet to "localhost". Try it on a live server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not an infinite `access_token`?
Anyway, I don't *think* this is how it should be done, refer to this [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-check-if-user-has-certian-permission-facebook-api/22/) for more information:

```
$isGranted = $facebook->api(array(
    "method"    => "users.hasAppPermission",
    "ext_perm"   => "publish_stream",
    "uid"       => 579187142
));
if($isGranted === "1")
    echo "Permission granted!";
```